# Show / Hide is working too fast

Tags: jquery, html

This is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#rozwin").on({
    mouseenter: function() {
      $("#rozwin").hide();
      $('.ukryjDoRozwiniecia').show();
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
      $("#rozwin").show();
      $('.ukryjDoRozwiniecia').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.ukryjDoRozwiniecia {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="rozwin">
    <a href="http://livetracking.evt.com.pl">
      <i style="font-size: 14px;" class="fa fa-desktop fa-fw"></i> Live Tracking System
    </a>
  </li>

  <li class="ukryjDoRozwiniecia">
    <a href="http://livetracking.evt.com.pl/">EVT</a>
  </li>
  <li class="ukryjDoRozwiniecia">
    <a href="http://ltrans.evt.com.pl/">L-TRANS</a>
  </li>
  <li class="ukryjDoRozwiniecia">
    <a href="http://intraco.evt.com.pl/">INTRACO</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I try to hide first li element and show 3 other. Why is it so fast?
[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/o347wtsh/)

Comment: You can pass a duration to hide or show. Look up the documentation.

Comment: Your logic is wrong. Hiding element on `mouseenter` then fires the `mouseleave` event bound on it. If you expect displayed elements to be persistent...

Comment: @patwoj98 You should bound `mouseenter/mouseleave` events to a common container

Comment: @patwoj98 check the answer. Same result what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Pass duration to `.show` and `.hide`. Duration will be in `milliseconds` and also attach `mouseleave` to `.ukryjDoRozwiniecia` and `mouseenter` to `#rozwin`

> Also try to keep it in a separate `<ul>`, so that it would not disturb
>   you on `mouseleave` of one particular `li`. Check the updated `html`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#rozwin").on('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).hide(400, function() {
      $('.ukryjDoRozwiniecia').show(300);
    });
  });
  $('.ukryjDoRozwiniecia').on('mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).hide(300, function() {
      $('#rozwin').show(300);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.ukryjDoRozwiniecia {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li id="rozwin"><a href="http://livetracking.evt.com.pl"><i style="font-size: 14px;" class="fa fa-desktop fa-fw"></i> Live Tracking System</a>

  </li>
</ul>
<ul class="ukryjDoRozwiniecia">
  <li><a href="http://livetracking.evt.com.pl/">EVT</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="http://ltrans.evt.com.pl/">L-TRANS</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="http://intraco.evt.com.pl/">INTRACO</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: But when I want to show as long as the mouse is on elements. There is hide after a second.

Comment: It is because your hovered element hide

Comment: @ketan Even I did the same mistake. `:P`

Comment: I can change it. But I need to know what I should do.

Comment: Updated answer.. @patwoj98.. :)

Comment: @PraveenKumar.. Same here.. :D

Comment: But that's not valid HTML markup, even you can easily fix it

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this one
//change in html
 <li id="rozwin"><a href="http://livetracking.evt.com.pl"><i style="font-size: 14px;" class="fa fa-desktop fa-fw"></i> Live Tracking System</a></li>
<div id="ukryjDoRozwiniecia">


          <li class="ukryjDoRozwiniecia"><a href="http://livetracking.evt.com.pl/">EVT</a></li>
          <li class="ukryjDoRozwiniecia"><a href="http://ltrans.evt.com.pl/">L-TRANS</a></li>
          <li class="ukryjDoRozwiniecia"><a href="http://intraco.evt.com.pl/">INTRACO</a></li> 

          </div>
//change in js
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#rozwin").on({
        mouseenter: function () {
            $("#rozwin").hide();
            $('.ukryjDoRozwiniecia').show();
        }
    });

    $("#ukryjDoRozwiniecia").on({
        mouseleave: function () {
            $( "#rozwin").show();
            $('.ukryjDoRozwiniecia').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: So close, How change the HTML to don't hide elements when I go to L-Trans or INTRACO?

Comment: @patwoj98 try modified answer